# C programming error float

Tags: c, algorithm

This is the code. S (arithmetic mean) is done right, I have valid result. But for other calculations I'm getting this error: `Floating point exception (core dumped)`.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main () {
   int a,b,c;

   double s,h,g,k;

   printf ("unesite 3 cela broja\n");

   scanf ("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);

   s=(a+b+c)/3;

   printf ("aritmeticka s.v. je: %.2lf\n", s);

   /* this should be formula for medium value of harmonic number */
   h=3/((1/a)+(1/b)+(1/c)); 

   printf ("harmonijska s.v. je: %.2lf\n", h);

   /* this should be http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/a/f/f/aff7a590d055d563ceea52fd66fe7ee2.png */
   k=sqrt ((pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)+pow(c,2))/3);

   printf ("kvadratna s.v. je: %.2lf\n", k);

   /* and this http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/3/4/e348daea2f4f2bb60f5cb40706fcbad4.png */
   g=pow(a*b*c,1/3); 

   printf ("geometrijska s.v. je: %.2lf\n", g);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you are getting core dump, then I guess you can just use gdb to get backtrace and it will provide more information

Comment: 3/(1/a+1/b+1/c) etc will will not be "correct" very often, you need to use floating point arithmentics to get the result you are expecting. Same for 1/3 (which is 0) unlike 1.0/3 (0.33<repeating, of course>). Anyway, the reason for the exception is bound to be division by zero, you can find this out by using gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all your divisions are *integer* divisions. And if you divide an integer with a larger value then the result will be truncated to *zero*. Division by zero is not good, and will abort your program.

Change those divisions to *floating point* divisions.